# Xubuntu, make a launcher for a .sh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, launcher, gnome-terminal

I use Xubuntu with gnome-terminal.

I need to launch a sh script (restart.sh) on the pc startup. 
The .sh file is in this directory: "/home/stark/Desktop/Tracking/Release/5600/"

I created a launcher like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My GUI App
Exec=gnome-terminal -x sh -c "/home/stark/Desktop/Tracking/Release/5600/restart.sh"
Icon=/path/to/you/icon.svg
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Name[en_US]=Intel5600
Comment=
Path=
```

What's wrong? Thank you!

EDIT:

This is the bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'python3 main00.py'
```

If I start it from its folder it works (if in a terminal I type: ./restart.sh), but from the launcher it doesn't work.

I tried to set terminal=false, but nothing changes.

Comment: I wouldn't comment much on the command for `Exec` but `Terminal=false` looks like what you are after

Comment: Hi! It doesn't work. I will update the decription with the bash file...

Comment: If you want to run the `.sh` at startup why do you need a `.desktop` ?

Comment: How can I do it without a .desktop?

Comment: Just add it to *Session and Startup* with the full path to the `.sh`

Comment: I added the .sh in the Session and Startup but nothing happened.
In the command line I just clicked on the folder icon and pointed to the file, so in the command line there is this: /home/stark/Desktop/Tracking/Release/server.sh

Comment: Sorry if the name and the directory changed but is the same of before

Comment: Does the sh script have the executable bit set?

Comment: Yes, if I run it from the terminal it works...

Answer (score 0):

add an @reboot cron task:

1. Running `crontab -e` will allow you to edit your cron.
2. Adding a line like this to it:

   @reboot /path/to/script

will execute that script once your computer boots up.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 if it's important

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/rc.local
```

with content like the following:

```
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
/path/to/my/script.sh || exit 1   # Added by me
exit 0
```